# Is it possible to control which physical volume is used for a given logical volume in LVM?

Tags: lvm

If I have a volume group spanning multiple PVs, when I create a new LV, can I specify which PV it is stored on?  What about for snapshots?

I'm envisioning a scenario with a volume group made up of an SSD and a larger HDD.  I would like my root and home LVs to reside on the SSD, but use the HDD for additional storage and for transient snapshots.

It appears this could be done by starting with just one disk in the VG, creating the main partitions to its extents (as Linear type), and then adding the second disk and extending the VG onto it.  I'm wondering if there's an actual supported way to do it though.  Couldn't see anything in the lvcreate man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official LVM Documentation:

```
To create a logical volume to be allocated from a specific physical
volume  in the volume group, specify the physical volume or volumes at the 
end at the lvcreate command line. The following command creates a logical 
volume named testlv in volume group testvg allocated from the physical 
volume /dev/sdg1,

    lvcreate -L 1500 -ntestlv testvg /dev/sdg1
```